# Regex: test if character 1 appears before character 2 anywhere in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble making sense of a regex. I need a regex to test a url. I would like the regex to match if `?` comes before `#` anywhere in the string.

Want to pass:
- `test.com/?test=thisshouldmatch#/asjldfj/lskjdf`

Want to fail
- `test.com/#/thisshouldfail?test=laskjdflkajsd`

I thought a lookahead would be good for this, but I need it to not be restricted to matching only if the characters are immediately after each other.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cG3iR9/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a lookahead. Just match a `?` followed by anything followed by `#`

```
string.match(/\?.*#/)
```

```js
var string = "test.com/?test=thisshouldmatch#/asjldfj/lskjdf";
var result = !!string.match(/\?.*#/);
console.log(string, result);

var string = "test.com/#/thisshouldfail?test=laskjdflkajsd";
var result = !!string.match(/\?.*#/);
console.log(string, result);
```

Comment: this is almost correct, but backwards, '\?.*#' was what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Run the snippet. The one that should match says `true`, the one that should fail says `false`. How is that backwards?

Comment: Make sure you've refreshed. I had it backwards at first and edited it.